# Not to Join tables depending on the conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

For example, I have two tables.

table a

```
id

1
2
3
4
5
```

table b

```
id  type
1   type1
2   type2
3   type3
4   type1
5   type1
1   type1
2   type1
5   type2
```

I join my tables.

```
select a.id, b.type from 
table a left join table b on
a.id = b. id
```

for id = 5 I get:

```
id    type 
5     type1
5     type2
```

I only need the id where type1

```
select a.id, b.type from 
table a left join table b on
a.id = b. id where b.type = 'type1'
```

for id = 5 I get:

```
id    type 
5     type1
```

id =5 also has type2 in table 2.

My problem is that I need to exclude the id value where there is at least one type2 value in the stat field.

**For id =5 I expect the **empty table. Because id =5 also hase type2****

Is it possible to realize this?
I tried to use exists, contains, but without result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use exists logic:

```sql
SELECT a.id, b.type
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE
    b.type = 'type1' AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tableB t
        WHERE t.id = b.id AND
              t.type = 'type2'
    );
```

Comment: `WHERE b.type = 'type1'` converts the join from a `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. If you want a `LEFT JOIN` then move the filter(s) from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.

Comment: @MT0 Actually, I think the OP wants an inner join here.  I blindly copied over the original query.

Answer (score 1):

This will be helpful to achieve the desired output.

```
SELECT *
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Table1
        WHERE id = t1.id AND type = 'type2'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second outer join and filter on the types in the join condition and check that the `type2` join does not match any rows:

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       b1.type
FROM   a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b b1
       ON     a.id    = b1.id
          AND b1.type = 'type1'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b b2
       ON     a.id    = b2.id
          AND b2.type = 'type2'
WHERE  b2.id IS NULL
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (id) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE b(id, type) AS
SELECT 1, 'type1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'type1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'type1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'type2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'type3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'type1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'type1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'type2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | type1 |
| 1 | type1 |
| 4 | type1 |
| 3 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E7qDpDwi)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Oracle you can also utilize the `MINUS` operator which is

> Used to return all rows in the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement

It requires a little trick to apply your scenario, which is to select `type1` from the second query to make the rows match the first query :

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       b1.type
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b b1
                    ON a.id = b1.id
                       AND b1.type = 'type1'
MINUS ALL
SELECT a.id,
       'type1'
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b b1
               ON a.id = b1.id
                  AND b1.type = 'type2'
```

Please also note that we use `MINUS ALL` otherwise Oracle would duplicate the results and you would only see one of the `1,type1` records.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gTVGbz_c) is adopted from @MTO's answer.

The result :

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | type1 |
| 1 | type1 |
| 4 | type1 |
| 3 | *null* |